# jQuery - Image Slider Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to make an image slider with jQuery. The images are kept in line and the images are sliding from right to left. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="1" style="width: 100%; min-height: 100%; display: inline;"><img src="1.png" /></div>
<div id="2" style="width: 100%; min-height: 100%; display: inline;"><img src="2.png" /></div>
<div id="3" style="width: 100%; min-height: 100%; display: inline;"><img src="3.png" /></div>
```

And here's the jQUery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    i = 1
    setInterval(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({
            marginLeft: -($("#"+i).offset().left/2)
        }, 1500, "swing");
        i = ++i % 4;
        if(i==0) i = 1
        console.log(i);
    }, 2500);

});
```

**What I expect is:**
Obivo, to slide images one by one and if it's the third image then the first image should come up again and so on..

The problem is that this doesn't always slides the right way. Sometimes it just moves only 1px and sometimes it moves perfectly and sometimes it just makes the body animate to extreme right. To get you cleared, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enJLG/).

Comment: what is ur expected behavior?

Comment: Obivo, to slide images one by one and if it's the third image then the first image should come up again and so on..

Comment: i can suggest you to try using http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/ where you can set to slide images automatic

Comment: id's cannot start with numbers

Comment: No, @user2167382 The images are shown as the background on my website so it's **not** possible to do that actually. :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui try this http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/enJLG/1/

Answer (score 0):

As I sayed in the comment ID's cannot start with number. So try changing it like

```
<div id="mydiv_1" ...
<div id="mydiv_2" ...
<div id="mydiv_3" ...
```

and change it here

```
...
marginLeft: -($("#mydiv_"+i).offset().left/2)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem by changing the algo and did this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    i = 1
    setInterval(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            marginLeft: -(($("#mydiv" + i).width()*i)/2)
        }, 1500, "swing");
        ++i;
        if(i == 3) i = 0
        console.log(i);
    }, 2500);

});
```

Just removed the `offset` thing and used `width()*i` to make it work the right way. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you to have rotating effect,

Simple CSS will be :

```
 #mainDiv {
        position: relative;
        width: 980px;
        height: 347px;
    }

    .images {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <img class="images" src="~/1.jpg" width="980" height="347" />
    <img class="images" src="~/2.jpg" width="980" height="347" />
    <img class="images" src="~/3.jpg" width="980" height="347" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var ImageRotator =
    {
        init: function () {
            var initialFadeIn = 1000;
            var itemInterval = 2500;
            var fadeTime = 1500;

            var numberOfItems = $('.images').length;
            var currentItem = 0;
            $('.images').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);
            var imageLoop = setInterval(function () {
                $('.images').eq(currentItem)
                 .fadeOut(fadeTime);

                if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
                    currentItem = 0;
                } else {
                    currentItem++;
                }
                $('.images').eq(currentItem)
                 .fadeIn(fadeTime);

            }, itemInterval);
        }
    };

    ImageRotator.init();

});
```